# Reading ASCII file in Python (numpy-array?)

Tags: python, numpy, ascii

I have a problem reading ASCII file in Python. Here's an example of the file: http://pastebin.com/CTwwPPKA

I tried using numpy's genfromtxt:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("example.txt")
```

But this way I cannot read dates and times properly since they should be datetime objects.
On the other hand, loadtxt can only read float values, which is also not acceptable.

Could you please suggest me a way to properly read that kind of file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use `dtype` option here.

```
x = np.genfromtxt("example.txt", dtype=None)
print(x[0])
```

and you will get

```
('DATA', 34967565, '2011-08-04', '19:00:00:081', 0.0272448, -0.17718500000000001, 4.2143899999999999, 524.57600000000002, 17.485499999999998, 101.07599999999999, 0.45927400000000002, 0.19031300000000001, 0.100296, 0.97492599999999996, 1.94354, 100.73399999999999, 12.538600000000001, 10.3786, 44318.5, 39605.5, 39234.5, 40298.0, 68)
```

The trick here is that you have to specify `dtype` to `None` so that numpy can automatically recognize strings and numbers, while the default `dtype` is float.

Then you can use [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert the strings to datetime objects accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`csv.reader()`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader) with the [`csv.excel_tab`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.excel_tab) dialect.

[Examples of `csv` usage](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples)

Comment: The problem is that the file has both tab and space delimiters.

Comment: Not according to what you pasted.