# Python array of datetime objects from numpy ndarray

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have numpy ndarray which contains two columns: one is date, e.g. 2011-08-04, another one is time, e.g. 19:00:00:081.

How can I combine them into one array of datetime objects? Currently, they're strings in numpy array.

Comment: What's the `dtype` of the array?  Are the columns `object`s or fix-length string fields?

Comment: @Sven Marnach: this is a continuation of [reading ascii file...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497328/reading-ascii-file-in-python-numpy-array)

Comment: @ykt: Can you remove the tab between `2011-08-04` and `19:00:00:08` when creating the original text file? If there is no whitespace, there is a slick way to form the right array with `np.genfromtxt` (without having to merge columns).

Comment: @unutbu: Unfortunately no, there're thousands of them and there're more to come! However, I would really like to have a look at your version as well.

Comment: If `a` is your array, you can access its `dtype` using `a.dtype`.  If the columns are fixed-width string columns, this would allow for a minor optimisation as we can skip the step of joining them by reinterpreting the data.  This would not be possible if they are Python `str` objects.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Okay, the dtypes are S10 and S12 respectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the date and time string in the [example.txt](http://pastebin.com/CTwwPPKA) data file were given as one column with no separating whitespace, then `genfromtxt` could convert it into a datetime object like this:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
def mkdate(text):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%f')    
data = np.genfromtxt(
    'example.txt',
    names=('data','num','date')+tuple('col{i}'.format(i=i) for i in range(19)),
    converters={'date':mkdate},
    dtype=None)
```

---

Given `example.txt` as it is, you could form the desired numpy array with

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import csv

def mkdate(text):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S:%f')    

def using_csv(fname):
    desc=([('data', '|S4'), ('num', '<i4'), ('date', '|O4')]+
          [('col{i}'.format(i=i), '<f8') for i in range(19)])
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
        data=np.array([tuple(row[:2]+[mkdate(''.join(row[2:4]))]+row[4:])
                       for row in reader],
                      dtype=desc)
    # print(mc.report_memory())        
    return data
```

Merging two columns in a numpy array can be a slow operation especially if the array is large. That's because merging, like resizing, requires allocating memory for a new array, and copying data from the original array to the new one. So I think it is worth trying to form the correct numpy array directly, instead of in stages (by forming a partially correct array and merging two columns).

---

By the way, I tested the above `csv` code versus merging two columns (below).  Forming a single array from `csv` (above) was faster (and the memory usage was about the same):

```
import matplotlib.cbook as mc
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

def using_genfromtxt(fname):
    data = np.genfromtxt(fname, dtype=None)

    orig_desc=data.dtype.descr
    view_desc=orig_desc[:2]+[('date','|S22')]+orig_desc[4:]
    new_desc=orig_desc[:2]+[('date','|O4')]+orig_desc[4:]

    newdata = np.empty(data.shape, dtype=new_desc)
    fields=data.dtype.names
    fields=fields[:2]+fields[4:]
    for field in fields:
        newdata[field] = data[field]

    newdata['date']=np.vectorize(mkdate)(data.view(view_desc)['date'])
    # print(mc.report_memory())

    return newdata  

# using_csv('example4096.txt')
# using_genfromtxt('example4096.txt')
```

`example4096.txt` is the same as `example.txt`, duplicated 4096 times. It's about 12K lines long.

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_genfromtxt("example4096.txt")'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.92 sec per loop

% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_csv("example4096.txt")'
10 loops, best of 3: 982 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as it is, given a two-column NumPy array `a`, you could do

```
b = numpy.array([datetime.datetime.strptime(s + t, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S:%f")
                 for s, t in a])
```

Since the comments indicate that the original array `a` is constructed using `genfromtxt()`, you are probably better off joining the columns in the text file and defining a suitable converter (see the [`converters` argument to `genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt)).

**Edit**: If the columns are of types `S10` and `S12` respectively as indicated in the comments, you can do a minor optimisation of this code since you don't need to explicitly join the columns:

```
a = numpy.array([("2011-08-04", "19:00:00:081"), 
                 ("2011-08-04", "19:00:00:181")], 
                dtype=[("", "S10"), ("", "S12")])
b = numpy.array([datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S:%f")
                 for s in a.view("S22")])
```

The operation `a.view("S22")` is cheap as it does not copy the data.  If your array is really big, this optimisation might be welcome, though it does not make a huge difference.