# How to combine two datetime arrays in one datetime array?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

I have two arrays with datetime objects, but I need only one combined array with date of the first and time of the second..
If I use

> `datetime.combine(date,time)`

the result is

> TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not
>   numpy.ndarray

the code is:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import math
from datetime import datetime, time, date
from glob import glob
import pylab as plb
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import asarray as ar,exp
#importo i nomi dei files

fnames=glob('C:/Users/asus/Desktop/lab_astro/GALASSIA/galassia canale 43/*')
#conto i files per ogni tipo e inizializzo le variabili dove mettere i dati
num_file14=len(fnames)
signal14=[]
dt = datetime
dd = datetime


#leggo i files e riempio le variabiliChange working directory..
for n in range (0, num_file14):
    data14=np.loadtxt(fnames[n], comments ='END', delimiter=';', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,7),dtype=object,converters={ 0: lambda x: dd.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y"),1: lambda x: dt.strptime(x, "%H.%M.%S") , 7: np.float}) 
    dd=np.append(orario,data14[:,0])
    dt=np.append(orario,data14[:,1])
    d = datetime.combine(dd,dt)
    signal14=np.append(signal14,data14[:,2])
```

maby my question is naive, I'm new in Python, but I really need this program to work...thanks for your help!!

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/7501549/524743

Comment: Can you provide the values od `dd` and `dt`. I think it's need to convert to `datetime` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables `dd` and `dt` are in `numpy.ndarray` format. It's need to convert to `datetime` format. 
Look at the working of `datetime.combine(date,time)`

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: time = datetime.time(12,12,12)
In [3]: date = datetime.date(2015,1,04)
In [4]: datetime.datetime.combine(date,time)
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 4, 12, 12, 12)
```

I hope `dd` represent for `date` and `dt` represent for `time`. So your code changed like this.

```
datetime.datetime.combine(dd.date(),dt.time())
```

If you are using iteration. You have to change the code as per the iteration

Comment: thakyou, I see.. now, the conversion is my problem! dd is like : 
Out[112]: 
array([<type 'datetime.datetime'>, datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0)], dtype=object)

Comment: Please use code formatting in comment also. It' difficult to read.

Comment: I think it's  a `numpy.ndarray` with elements of `datetime` variables. So you can iterate through that and use the `datetime.combine(date,time)`.

Comment: ok, something like this?

`for n in range (0, num_file14): 
    orario = np.append(datetime.combine(dd[n],dt[n]))`

the result is:

**TypeError: combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not type**
 
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: From your first comments it's seems like your first element is a `type` representation. Solve that one.

Comment: I haven't already fix it.. dt and dd are two arrays of datetime objects:
`dt[1]
Out[1]: datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 19, 23)`

`dd[1]
Out[2]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 16, 0, 0)`
 
but, I don't know why, _datetime.combine(date,time)_ doesn't work.

Comment: @Agni Your `dd` and `dt` are same format. It's should be date and time. It's appears both having date and time values. How you going to combine them ?

Comment: unfortunately when I import datas from several file.txt, I have to use _strptime_ in this way:

`data14=np.loadtxt(fnames[n], comments ='END', delimiter=';', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,7),dtype=object,converters={ 0: lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d/%m/%Y"),1: lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H.%M.%S") , 7: np.float}) `

if I _use datetime.time_ or _datetime.date_ instead of _datetime.datetime_, it doesn't work.